# Responsive Web Design: Inner DIV's in a wrapper DIV - Want the inner DIV's to stack on top of each other on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like the inner div's `left` and `right` to be centered in the wrapper div at all times, and when the device screen is less than 600 px, the `right` inner div to go below the `left` inner div.

I have made many attempts to figure it out, but to no avail yet. All my code is on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vdwz3csp/5/

This is my html code:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        <span>
            <img
                class="wp-image-440 size-medium aligncenter"
                src="http://www.generalgreenestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/danielgreene-circle-300x300.png"
                alt="Daniel Greene"
                width="200"
                height="200" />
        </span>

        <span class="about-desc">
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                <strong>Daniel Greene</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                Cinematographer/Editor
            </p>

            <hr style="border-color: #333333;" />
            <p style="text-align: justify;">
                Text here
            </p>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <span>
            <img
                class="wp-image-435 size-medium aligncenter"
                src="http://www.generalgreenestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/alexandriagreene-circle-300x300.png"
                alt="Alexandria Greene"
                width="200"
                height="200" />
        </span>

        <span class="about-desc">
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                <strong>Alexandria Greene</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                Accounts/Client Relations
            </p>

            <hr style="border-color: #333333;" />
            <p style="text-align: justify;">
                Some text goes here
            </p>
        </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my css code:

```
#wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #right {
    padding: 20px;
    width:25%;
    min-width:300px;
    float:left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #left {
        float:none;
        width:auto;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #right {
        float:none;
        width:auto;
        margin:50px auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `flex-direction`

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdwz3csp/7/

```
#wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:row;
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #right {
    padding: 20px;
    width:25%;
    min-width:300px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #wrap
    {
        flex-direction:column;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel dumb now.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap `display` of the `#wrap` from `flex` to plain `block` in mobile query: https://jsfiddle.net/vdwz3csp/8/

Comment: Also equally effective. Thanks!